# Android 10: Camera2 Effects not shown in camera preview

Tags: java, android-studio, camera, android-camera2, android-10.0

I made a simple camera App using `Camera2 API`, but i have a problem with showing effects in the preview using android 10.

Running the app on OnePlus 5T (Android 9.0), Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 (Android 8.0) and Asus Zenfone 2 Laser (Android 7.1), the effect is correctly applied in both the preview and the photo taken.

[image: Camera Preview on android 9] [image: Photo Taken on android 9]

Testing it on Oneplus 7 Pro, Xiaomi Mi 9T, Huawei P30 Pro (Android 10), the effect is not shown in the preview, while is applied once the photo is taken.

[image: Camera Preview on android 10] [image: Photo Taken on android 10]

I used in order to apply the effect the following code

```
previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);  
pictureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);    
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE);
pictureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE);
```

Any idea? I'm pretty sure that the problem is in something changed with `CameraMetadata` or `CaptureRequest` in android 10, but i haven't found nothing useful.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I need the solution of the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this change appears nowhere in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check multicamera support news for android 10